# Django OperationError when trying to create an entry

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, operationalerror

I'm receiving the following OperationError when I try to add a new post using my superuser on the admin site.

```
OperationalError at /admin/blog/post/add/

table blog_post has no column named author_id

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/post/add/
Django Version:     4.2.1
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

table blog_post has no column named author_id
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in my models.py
This is the class I created for this table

```
class Post(models.Model):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                              choices=Status.choices,
                              default=Status.DRAFT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-publish']),
        ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

I just have set admin.py and settings.py to recognize the class, and database migrations are done but the error persists.

The migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(max_length=250)),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('publish', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[('DF', 'Draft'), ('PB', 'Published')], default='DF', max_length=2)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['-publish'],
                'indexes': [models.Index(fields=['-publish'], name='blog_post_publish_bb7600_idx')],
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Here are the results of python manage.py showmigrations

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
blog
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: Can you show the migration file for this change please? Can you also run ./manage.py showmigrations and check that the migration has definitely run?

Comment: I'll update the post with the migration file

Answer (score 0):

Typically you wouldn't access the column by using 'author_id' it would be accessed using 'authur.id'. Django does a lot of manipulations behind the scene.  It has to translate the table into a class, and the class convention uses a period instead of an underscore.  Could you provide the code where you're trying to access the column if this doesn't work?

Comment: This error was related to the migration process:
I solved this by doing the following:
delete the migration file (except the __init__.py)
python manage.py makemigrations blog
python manage.py migrate

with the reconstituted migrations folder, the error just gone

Comment: Good job arielkoo, it seems that the author foreign key was missing from the migration file you uploaded, which by deleting it and creating it again has resolved it.